# UWP - StreamSocket connection error for some connections

Tags: sockets, uwp, stream, stream-socket-client

We have 2 UWP apps. One app shares data to the other app through StreamSocket. The server app will send data to client app. There will be 30-40 or more devices running the client app and connecting to the server's socket to receive data.

When we test with one client app, all the data sharing happens without any issue. But when we started testing with about 10 devices using the client app, sometimes some apps don't receive data. And there seems to be an error saying **A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond**

In general it get shared to most of the devices, but few fails sometimes randomly. What could be the reason for this? Is there a connection limit to connect to a socket with given IP and port using Stream Socket?

Here is some parts of our code. Please let me know what we have to correct here to avoid getting that error.

**Server side**

```
        public async Task StartServer(string serverIp, string serverPort)
        {
            try
            {

                HostName serverAddress = new HostName(serverIp);
                //Create a StreamSocketListener to start listening for TCP connections.
                StreamSocketListener socketListener = new StreamSocketListener();

                //Hook up an event handler to call when connections are received.
                socketListener.ConnectionReceived += SocketListener_ConnectionReceived;

                //Start listening for incoming TCP connections on the specified port.
                await socketListener.BindEndpointAsync(serverAddress, serverPort);                                              
            }              
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }

        private async void SocketListener_ConnectionReceived(StreamSocketListener sender, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
        {
            try
            {
                await Task.Run(() => ShareFile(args.Socket));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
```

**Client side**

```
        public async Task ServerConnect(string serverIP, string serverPort)
        {
            try
            {
                HostName serverAddress = new HostName(serverIP);
                StreamSocket socket = new StreamSocket();

                socket.Control.KeepAlive = false;            

                // Connect to the server.
                await socket.ConnectAsync(serverAddress, serverPort, SocketProtectionLevel.PlainSocket);            
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
```

Also would like to get these clarified

-What is the difference between BindServiceNameAsync and BindEndpointAsync? Most examples seems to use the first one. When should we use the second one?

-If we call sender.Dispose(); in SocketListener_ConnectionReceived, will that affect the other clients trying to join the same socket?

-In the ShareFile() function, if we close args.Socket() after sending data, can it close the socket before the client actually read the data from that side?

Comment: Have you tried  to set `KeepAlive` as true?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT closing the StreamSocketListener and the sockets seems to fix most of the issues. But have to test with 20-30 clients to see how it goes.  What actually happens with KeepAlive true? Couldn't get a clear idea from the documentation.